# tkinter image change within a label when i gpio state changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gpio

i am trying to use an image inside a label to show a change in the gpio state, i have been able to use text to change but now would like to use a picture of and led and a fish image. but i cant get it to find the image.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#Setup input GPIO pins for use with optical infrared sensors
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # SUMP LOW WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # SUMP NORM WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # SUMP HIGH WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # RO LOW WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)   # DISPLAY HIGH WATER LEVEL
#GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # MAY USE AS PROTIEN SKIMMER SENSOR
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # DISPLAY LOW WATER LEVEL SENSOR
#setup output pins for relay control
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)   #return pump 1 ch 1 cutoff relay in series with GPIO(8)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)   #return pump 2 ch 2 relay
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)   #gyre pump ch3 relay
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)   #used for return pump 1
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.OUT)   #power head 2 ch 5 relay
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)  #power head 1 ch 
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)   # AUTO TOP OFF PUMP
#Setup output GPIO pins for use with Red Yellow and Green LEDS
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)  # DISPLAY HIGH WATER LEVEL RED LED
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)  # DISPLAY NORM WATER LEVEL GREEN LED
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)  # DISPLAY LOW WATER LEVEL YELLOW LED
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)  # AUTO TOP OFF LOW LEVEL RED LED
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)  # SUMP HIGH WATER LEVEL RED LED
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT)  # SUMP NORMAL WATER LEVEL GREEN LED
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)  # SUMP LOW WATER LEVEL YELLOW LED
#setup fonts
ftb= 'Verdana', 12, 'bold'
def photo2():

    photo2= oraled.png
#setup class for the tk program
class gpio(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)
        root.title("trial")
        root.geometry("430x830")
        root.configure(bg="lightblue")
    #setup image 
        root.photo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="fish.gif") #defines a photo and gives the file name
        root.label1 = tk.Label(root, image=root.photo1)#puts label in the window in this case not text file must be in program folder
        root.label1.place(x=0, y=0) #says how to place the label
#setup display high sensor label
        root.photo2 = tk.PhotoImage(file='oraled.png')
        root.dishisensorlabel= tk.Label(root, image="")
        root.dishisensorlabel.place(x=210, y=500)

        labeldishisensor= tk.Label(root,text=("Display High"), font=(ftb), fg="black")
        labeldishisensor.place(x=0, y=500)        


        root.update_gpio()
    def update_gpio(root):
        dhsen =('fish.gif' if GPIO.input(5) else 'oraled')
        root.dishisensorlabel.configure(image=dhsen)    

        root.after(200, root.update_gpio)

if __name__== "__main__":
    app = gpio()
    app.mainloop()
```

i get the following errors i am running this in thorney while i delevelop the script

```
>>> %Run 'use of images for leds.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/use of images for leds.py", line 63, in <module>
    app = gpio()
  File "/home/pi/use of images for leds.py", line 55, in __init__
    root.update_gpio()
  File "/home/pi/use of images for leds.py", line 58, in update_gpio
    root.dishisensorlabel.configure(image=dhsen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "fish.gif" doesn't exist
>>>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why-edoes-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091)

Comment: i think its to do with the way i am trying to call up either one or the other in the following part of the script -----------------                                                                          root.update_gpio()
    def update_gpio(root):
        dhsen =('fish.gif' if GPIO.input(5) else 'oraled')
        root.dishisensorlabel.configure(image=dhsen)

Comment: You can't just assign the image filename to `image` option of `Label`.  You need to load the image to an instance of `PhotoImage` and assign this instance to `image` option instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[final code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcDW1.png)

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#Setup input GPIO pins for use with optical infrared sensors
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # SUMP LOW WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # SUMP NORM WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # SUMP HIGH WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # RO LOW WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)   # DISPLAY HIGH WATER LEVEL
#GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # MAY USE AS PROTIEN SKIMMER SENSOR
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # DISPLAY LOW WATER LEVEL SENSOR
#setup output pins for relay control
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)   #return pump 1 ch 1 cutoff relay in series with GPIO(8)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)   #return pump 2 ch 2 relay
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)   #gyre pump ch3 relay
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)   #used for return pump 1
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.OUT)   #power head 2 ch 5 relay
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)  #power head 1 ch 
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)   # AUTO TOP OFF PUMP
#Setup output GPIO pins for use with Red Yellow and Green LEDS
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)  # DISPLAY HIGH WATER LEVEL RED LED
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)  # DISPLAY NORM WATER LEVEL GREEN LED
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)  # DISPLAY LOW WATER LEVEL YELLOW LED
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)  # AUTO TOP OFF LOW LEVEL RED LED
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)  # SUMP HIGH WATER LEVEL RED LED
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT)  # SUMP NORMAL WATER LEVEL GREEN LED
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)  # SUMP LOW WATER LEVEL YELLOW LED
#setup fonts
ftb= 'Verdana', 12, 'bold'
#setup class for the tk program
class gpio(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)
        root.title("Heads Up")
        root.geometry("430x830")
        root.Greenoff= tk.PhotoImage(file="greenoff.png")
        root.Greenon= tk.PhotoImage(file="GreenOnworking.png")
        root.Yellowoff= tk.PhotoImage(file="yellowoff.png")
        root.Yellowon= tk.PhotoImage(file="yellowon.png")        
        root.Redoff= tk.PhotoImage(file="redoff.png")
        root.Redon= tk.PhotoImage(file="redon.png")    
        root.pumpoffnew= tk.PhotoImage(file="pumpoffnew.png")
        root.pumponnew= tk.PhotoImage(file="pumponnew.png")
        root.pumpoffr= tk.PhotoImage(file="pumpoffr.png")
        root.pumponr= tk.PhotoImage(file="pumponr.png")
        root.pwrhdon= tk.PhotoImage(file="pwrhdon.png")
        root.pwrhdoff= tk.PhotoImage(file="pwrhdoff.png")
        root.gyreon= tk.PhotoImage(file="gyreon.png")
        root.gyreoff= tk.PhotoImage(file="gyreoff.png")
        root.sensorin= tk.PhotoImage(file="sensorin.png")
        root.sensorout= tk.PhotoImage(file="sensorout.png")
        root.lowsensorin= tk.PhotoImage(file="lowsensorin.png")
        root.lowsensorout= tk.PhotoImage(file="lowsesorout.png")
        root.normsensorin= tk.PhotoImage(file="normsensorin.png")
        root.normsensorout= tk.PhotoImage(file="normsesorout.png")
        root.highsensorin= tk.PhotoImage(file="highsensorin.png")
        root.disphighsensorout= tk.PhotoImage(file="disphighsesorout.png")
    #setup image 
        root.photo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="background.png") #defines a photo and gives the file name
        root.label1 = tk.Label(root, image=root.photo1)#puts label in the window in this case not text file must be in program folder
        root.label1.place(x=0, y=0) #says how to place the label
    #setup exit button
        Exitbutton= tk.Button(root, text="Exit", font=(ftb), width=5, bg="red", fg="white", command=root.destroy)
        Exitbutton.place(x=20, y=600)
    # setup display water high light
        root.dishighlabel =tk.Label(root,)
        root.dishighlabel.place(x=291, y=91)

    # setup display water norm  light
        root.disnormlabel =tk.Label(root,)
        root.disnormlabel.place(x=203, y=91)

    # setup display water low light
        root.dislowlabel =tk.Label(root,)
        root.dislowlabel.place(x=114, y=91)

    # setup sump water high light
        root.sumphighlabel =tk.Label(root,)
        root.sumphighlabel.place(x=218, y=287)

    # setup sump water norn light
        root.sumpnormlabel=tk.Label(root,)
        root.sumpnormlabel.place(x=154, y=287)

        root.sumplowlabel=tk.Label(root,)
        root.sumplowlabel.place(x=90, y=287)

    # setup Ato water low light label
        root.atopledsensorlabel=tk.Label(root,)
        root.atopledsensorlabel.place(x=337, y=287)

    #set up return pump 1 labels
        root.rtnp1label = tk.Label(root,)
        root.rtnp1label.place(x=45, y=330)


    #setup return pump 2 labels                  
        root.rtnp2label = tk.Label(root,)
        root.rtnp2label.place(x=250, y=330)


    #setup gyre pump labels
        root.gyrelabel =tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.gyrelabel.place(x=357, y=65)


    #setup powerhead 1 labels
        root.pwrhd1label = tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.pwrhd1label.place(x=43, y=65)


    #setup powerhead 2 labels
        root.pwrhd2label = tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.pwrhd2label.place(x=43, y=95)

    #setup ato pump labels
        root.atoppumplabel = tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.atoppumplabel.place(x=312, y=330)



    #setup display high sensor label
        root.dishisensorlabel= tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.dishisensorlabel.place(x=0, y=30)


    #setup display low sensor label
        root.dislosensorlabel= tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.dislosensorlabel.place(x=0, y=82)


    #setup sump high sensor label
        root.sumhisensorlabel= tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.sumhisensorlabel.place(x=0, y=227)

    #setup sump norm sensor label
        root.sumnorsensorlabel= tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.sumnorsensorlabel.place(x=0, y=279)
        
    #setup sump low sensor label
        root.sumlowsensorlabel= tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.sumlowsensorlabel.place(x=0, y=332)

    #setup ato sensor label
        root.atopsensorlabel= tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.atopsensorlabel.place(x=399, y=335)


# start the GPIO checks"        
        root.update_gpio()

    def update_gpio(root):
    #sensors
        dhsen =(root.disphighsensorout if GPIO.input(5) else root.highsensorin)
        root.dishisensorlabel.configure(image=dhsen,)
        dlsen =(root.lowsensorout if GPIO.input(13) else root.lowsensorin)
        root.dislosensorlabel.configure(image=dlsen,)
        shsen =(root.disphighsensorout if GPIO.input(22) else root.highsensorin)
        root.sumhisensorlabel.configure(image=shsen,)
        snsen =(root.normsensorout if GPIO.input(27) else root.normsensorin)
        root.sumnorsensorlabel.configure(image=snsen,)
        slsen =(root.lowsensorout if GPIO.input(17) else root.lowsensorin)
        root.sumlowsensorlabel.configure(image=slsen,)
        atosen =(root.sensorout if GPIO.input(26) else root.sensorin)
        root.atopsensorlabel.configure(image=atosen,)

    #leds
        atop = (root.Redon if GPIO.input(12) else root.Greenon)
        root.atopledsensorlabel.configure(image=atop,)
        sumh = (root.Redon if GPIO.input(16) else root.Redoff)
        root.sumphighlabel.configure(image=sumh,)
        sumn = (root.Greenon if GPIO.input(20) else root.Greenoff)
        root.sumpnormlabel.configure(image=sumn,)
        suml = (root.Yellowon if GPIO.input(21) else root.Yellowoff)
        root.sumplowlabel.configure(image=suml,)
        dish = (root.Redon if GPIO.input(23) else root.Redoff)
        root.dishighlabel.configure(image=dish,)
        disn = (root.Greenon if GPIO.input(24) else root.Greenoff)
        root.disnormlabel.configure(image=disn,)
        disl = (root.Yellowon if GPIO.input(25) else root.Yellowoff)
        root.dislowlabel.configure(image=disl,)                            
    #pumps
        rt1 = (root.pumponnew if GPIO.input(2) else root.pumpoffnew)
        root.rtnp1label.configure(image=rt1,)
        rt2 = (root.pumponr if GPIO.input(3) else root.pumpoffr)
        root.rtnp2label.configure(image=rt2,)
        ph2 = (root.pwrhdon if GPIO.input(9) else root.pwrhdoff)
        root.pwrhd2label.configure(image=ph2,)
        ph1 = (root.pwrhdon if GPIO.input(11) else root.pwrhdoff)
        root.pwrhd1label.configure(image=ph1,)
        gyr = (root.gyreon if GPIO.input(4) else root.gyreoff)
        root.gyrelabel.configure(image=gyr,)
        top1 =(root.pumpoffnew if GPIO.input(7) else root.pumponnew)
        root.atoppumplabel.configure(image=top1,)
        
        # call this function again in one second
        root.after(1000, root.update_gpio)

if __name__== "__main__":
    app = gpio()
    app.mainloop()
```

hope this helps others trying to do this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for showing interest this is now working and i hope it helps others trying to similar scripts

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#Setup input GPIO pins for use with optical infrared sensors
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # SUMP LOW WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # SUMP NORM WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # SUMP HIGH WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # RO LOW WATER LEVEL SENSOR
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)   # DISPLAY HIGH WATER LEVEL
#GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # MAY USE AS PROTIEN SKIMMER SENSOR
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # DISPLAY LOW WATER LEVEL SENSOR
#setup output pins for relay control
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)   #return pump 1 ch 1 cutoff relay in series with GPIO(8)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)   #return pump 2 ch 2 relay
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)   #gyre pump ch3 relay
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)   #used for return pump 1
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.OUT)   #power head 2 ch 5 relay
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)  #power head 1 ch 
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)   # AUTO TOP OFF PUMP
#Setup output GPIO pins for use with Red Yellow and Green LEDS
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)  # DISPLAY HIGH WATER LEVEL RED LED
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)  # DISPLAY NORM WATER LEVEL GREEN LED
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)  # DISPLAY LOW WATER LEVEL YELLOW LED
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)  # AUTO TOP OFF LOW LEVEL RED LED
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)  # SUMP HIGH WATER LEVEL RED LED
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT)  # SUMP NORMAL WATER LEVEL GREEN LED
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)  # SUMP LOW WATER LEVEL YELLOW LED
#setup fonts
ftb= 'Verdana', 12, 'bold'

#setup class for the tk program
class gpio(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)
        root.title("trial")
        root.geometry("430x830")
        root.configure(bg="lightblue")
        root.photo2= tk.PhotoImage(file="whiteled.png")
        root.photo3= tk.PhotoImage(file='green.png')

    #setup image 
        root.photo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="fish.gif") #defines a photo and gives the file name
        root.label1 = tk.Label(root, image=root.photo1)#puts label in the window in this case not text file must be in program folder
        root.label1.place(x=0, y=0) #says how to place the label
    #setup display high sensor label
        root.dishisensorlabel= tk.Label(root, text="")
        root.dishisensorlabel.place(x=210, y=500)

        labeldishisensor= tk.Label(root,text=("Power Head 2"), font=(ftb), fg="black")
        labeldishisensor.place(x=0, y=500)        


        root.update_gpio()

    def update_gpio(root):

        dhsen =(root.photo3 if GPIO.input(9) else root.photo2)
        root.dishisensorlabel.configure(image=dhsen, text="")    

        root.after(200, root.update_gpio)

if __name__== "__main__":
    app = gpio()
    app.mainloop()
```

a few changes were required.